# Finitely generated abelian group isomorphic to infinite abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Lang's Algebra says that if an abelian group $A$ is free and finitely generated by $(x_i), i=1,\dots, n$ , then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}x_1 \bigoplus \cdots \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}x_n$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\cdots\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}$ ($n$-fold).  But if $A = A_{\text{tor}}$, i.e. a torsion group, then isn't $A \approx \mathbb{Z}/m_i\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\cdots\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/m_n\mathbb{Z}$, where $m_i = $ exponent of $x_i$, finite?  So can we have a finite group isomorphic to an infinite one?

Comment: In the first sentence, $A$ is a finitely generated ***free*** abelian group. In the second sentence, $A$ is a finitely generated ***torsion*** abelian group.

Comment: which is a free abelian group which is torsion.

Comment: The only abelian group that is both free and torsion is the trivial group.

Comment: So nontrivial torsion groups don't have a basis?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Yes. The independence condition implies that a torsion element can't be part of a basis.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: They have *generating sets*. Other than the trivial group, they do not have bases. I would advise you to think about what you mean by "basis" for an abelian group and see if you can understand why this is the case.

Comment: I guess I should have read more about torsion groups before posting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a finite group and an infinite group can't be isomorphic. $\mathbb Z$ (or $\mathbb Z\cdot x$) is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.

If one group has an element $y$ of infinite order, and a second group has no such element, then it's easy to show that the groups are not isomorphic. (Where would the isomorphism map $y$?)